# Request Recipient Token return different url in different account

Tags: docusignapi

I using the RequestRecipientToken soap service.  It was all working fine until we change to use a different demo account for testing.  Previously we were getting a token url of "https://demo.docusign.net/Signing/StartInSession.aspx?t=48e320ac-a37d-492e-9569-366718023231".

However with the new demo account, it's returning "https://demo.docusign.net/Signing/MTRedeem/v1?slt=xxx where xxx is a really long which is causing an issue because our application is truncating the url so it's invalid.  Not sure why there's a difference.  It's using the same service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DocuSign is currently rolling out a change in the Demo environment to how Signing Session tokens are handled. It looks like your new account is seeing the new behavior, while the existing account hasn't had the switch flipped yet. There is not currently a target date for when this will be implemented in Production.

The short answer is that you will need to update your behavior to not truncate the URL received from DocuSign.

**What's changing:**

Currently, Captive Signing Session URLs look like this: `https://demo.docusign.net/Signing/StartInSession.aspx?t=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`

After the change, the URL will be significantly longer. 
For example: `https://demo.docusign.net/Signing/MTRedeem/v1?slt=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000-000000000_00000000000000000000000000000000000000-000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000_000000000000000000000000000-0000000000000000000000000000000-00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000_0_0000000000000000000-00000_00000000000_0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000-000000000000000000000000000000000000`

Where the current URL only has a guid (36 hexadecimal characters with hyphens), the new format can be over a thousand characters, contain underscores and periods, and is case sensitive.

​**Additionally, there is a difference in behavior:**

the new format briefly routes the signer through the account server, so if you are using domain-based whitelisting in your application or network environment, you will need to confirm that *.docusign.com is whitelisted, in addition to the previous *.docusign.net.

Any system that is expecting the old format and limits the URL length accordingly will need to be updated to have that length restriction removed.